# Splitting a complex string with Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I, using a *regular expression*, split this **string**:

```
string = "a[a=d b&c[e[100&2=34]]] e[cheese=blue and white] x[a=a b]"
```

into this **array**:

```
string.split( regexp ) =>

[ "a[a=d b&c[e[100&2=34]]]", "e[cheese=blue and white]", "x[a=a b]" ]
```

The basic rule is that **string** should be split at **whitespace ( \s )**, unless **whitespace** exists inside **brackets( [ ] )**;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the rule is this simple, I would suggest just doing it manually.  Step through each character and keep track of your nesting level by increasing by 1 for each [ and decreasing by 1 for each ].  If you reach a space with nesting == 0 then split.

Edit:
I was thinking that I might also mention that there are other pattern matching facilities in some languages that do natively support this sort of thing.  For example, in Lua you can use '%b[]' to match balanced nested []'s.  (Of course, Lua doesn't have a built in split function....)

Comment: It is possible to do this with a regex when using Oniguruma, as it has an extension that allows certain types of nesting. However, I don't believe any javascript impl includes this extension, and regardless, I agree with Dolphin that a non-regex approach is going to be faster and cleaner. You can implement a state machine for this pretty easily.

Answer (score 5):

You can't; regular expressions are based on state machines which don't have a "stack" so you can remember the number of nesting levels.

But maybe you can use a trick: Try to convert the string into a valid [JSON string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Then you can use `eval()` to parse it into a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

could you split on "(?<=])\s(?=[a-z][)"? that is, a space preceeded by a ] and followed by a letter and a [? This assumes you never have any string inside brackets like "a[b=d[x=y b] g[w=v b]]"

Answer (score 0):

Another is a looping approach where you deconstruct the nested brackets one level at a time, else it's hard(TM) to ensure your single regexp will work as expected.

Here's an example in ruby:

```
str = "a[a=d b&c[e[100&2=34]]] e[cheese=blue and white] x[a=a b]"
left = str.dup
tokn=0
toks=[]
# Deconstruct
loop do
  left.sub!(/\[[^\]\[]*\]/,"\{#{tokn}\}")
  break if $~.nil?
  toks[tokn]=$&
  tokn+=1
end
left=left.split(/\s+/)
# Reconstruct
(toks.size-1).downto(0) do |tokn|
  left.each { |str| str.sub!("\{#{tokn}\}", toks[tokn]) }
end
```

The above uses {n} where n is an integer during the deconstruction, so in some cases original input like this in the string would break the reconstruction.  This should illustrate the approach though.

Writing code that does the split by iterating through the characters is simpler and safer though.

Example in ruby:

```
str = "a[a=d b&c[e[100&2=34]]] e[cheese=blue and white] x[a=a b]"
toks=[]
level=st=en=0; 
str.each_byte do |c|
  en+=1; 
  level+=1 if c=='['[0]; 
  level-=1 if c==']'[0]; 
  if level==0 && c==' '[0]
    toks.push(str[st,en-1-st]);
    st=en
  end
end    
toks.push(str[st,en-st]) if st!=en 
p toks
```